How to use later() with a function inside?
I am using the later function to print a custom function have in the future.
My function
custfunc <- function() {
head(mtcars)
}

> custfunc()
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

When I try to use the later::later() function, with my custom function inside of it I get the following error:
> later::later(custfunc(), 1 * 60)
Error in `later::later()`:
! Can't convert `func`, a data frame, to a function.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Anyone have any advice?

I don't use R, but could it be later::later(custfunc, 1*60)?

I suspect @WeijunZhou is correct -- the console parser replaces custfunc() with the output of said call.   You just want to pass the function name to later
